# (x)Ubuntu doesn't detect virtual hard drives

Tags: virtualization, windows-10, 15.10, hyper-v

I tried to install Ubuntu 15.10 on a Virtual Machine, created with Hyper-V on Windows 10 Pro.

But Ubuntu doesn't seem to detect the virtual drives in the VM.
[image: no free space for installation]

I tried to list the devices in the Live Version on the install medium - but nope
[image: list all devices]

My idea was, that Linux could have a problem with the virtual disks. So I tried a distribution, I've installed successfully on Hyper-V on Windows 8 multiple times - arch linux. But...
[image: disks on arch linux]

Does anyone have an idea what I am missing? Having three types of vhd... one dynamic vhdx, one dynamic vhd and one vhd with static size.
Thanks in advance

Comment: out put of "sudo fdisk -l"

Comment: /dev/ramx and /dev/loop0

Comment: @kuh-chan are you currently participating in the Windows 10 Insider Program and receiving the latest insider builds? There was a release about 10 days ago that may have recently been applied to your system. I have yet to confirm it but this may be the reason for my similar issue that I posted below. I'm currently running Windows 10 Insider Build 10565. I know I've had problems in the past with Insider builds directly affecting the behaviour of Hyper-V inside Windows 10. I'm currently in the process of downgrading to Windows 10 RTM and will let you know if that solves my problem.

Comment: @jenovachild yes, I am. I'm curious whether the downgrade worked for you :)

Comment: @kuh-chan Yes the downgrade worked for me. I was able to successfully boot my backed up Ubuntu 14 Server VM. It is definitely an issue with the latest Windows 10 Insider Build 10565

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also using this and having the same issue, after downgrading off of Windows 10 Build 10565 to the Windows 10 RTM it fixed the issue with Hyper-V for me.

The current Windows 10 Insider Build 10565 made some changes to Hyper-V including support for nested virtualization, but among these changes it has introduced issues with VM's running certain linux distros.

To downgrade from the Windows 10 Insider build, you are required to do a complete reinstall of Windows 10.

Comment: I've now installed Build 10576. It recognizes the hard drives. Finally. But I had to setup the Virtual Networks again; the old ones won't work anymory on my machine.